# How to share step binding class in SpecFlow with context injection

Tags: specflow

I'm using context injection in SpecFlow but I've encountered an issue whereby I want to share a step bindings class, but I don't necessarily need to register all the constructor parameters.

I have various BeforeScenario hooks in a separate binding/hooks class where I register objects with the container, like below....

```
[Scope(Scenario = "Scenario A")]
[BeforeScenario(Order = 5)]
public void CreateApprenticeWithChecklist()
{
    //Other stuff

    _container.RegisterInstanceAs<Apprentice>(apprentice);
}

[Scope(Scenario = "Scenario B")]
[BeforeScenario(Order = 5)]
public void CreateApprenticeWithChecklistAllSignOff()
{
    //Other stuff

    _container.RegisterInstanceAs<Apprentice>(apprentice);
    _container.RegisterInstanceAs<Dictionary<string, UserDetails>>(new Dictionary<string, UserDetails>
    {
        ["Employer"] = employer.Key,
        ["Training Provider"] = trainingProvider.Key
    });
}
```

I then have a step definitions class that both these scenarios will use....

```
[Binding]
public sealed class ApprenticeChecklistSteps
{
    private Apprentice _apprentice;
    private UserDetails _employer;
    private UserDetails _trainingProvider;   

    public ApprenticeChecklistSteps(Apprentice apprentice, Dictionary<string, UserDetails> userDetails)
    {
        _apprentice = apprentice;
        _employer = userDetails["Employer"];
        _trainingProvider = userDetails["Training Provider"];
    }

    //etc
```

The problem is if I'm running `Scenario A` there will be no registration for `Dictionary<string, UserDetails> userDetails` and so I will get the `Multiple public constructors with same maximum parameter count are not supported!` error.

How can I share step bindings between scenario's if I don't necessarily have or need a certain constructor parameter?

The only solutions I see are hacky

**Create 'blank' registrations for all the unused constructor parameters so they are initialized**

Or...

**Create a separate POCO that contains all the possible registrations, and register whatever I need, when I need it**

```
public class CheckListContext
{
    public Apprentice Apprentice { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, UserDetails> UserDetails { get; set; }
}
```

The registration in Scenario A `BeforeScenario` step would then become...

```
_container.RegisterInstanceAs<CheckListContext>(new CheckListContext{Apprentice = apprentice});
```

Comment: My understanding of hooks it to setup cross cutting concerns for a scenario.  i.e.  I'll have a web hook that starts up selenium and passes the webdriver around the various steps, then shut it down in an after hook.  If you are setting up data for a given test you should be setting that up in your Given step(s) since this data is relevant to the specific scenario.

Comment: @Fran I suppose, although it's generally a good idea to not include setup logic in your scenarios at all. That way you are purely focused on describing what you are trying to achieve. A one line 'Given' to describe the state may be suitable, but for many of my tests there is masses of setup data which can't coherently be described in one sentence. It's also not how the user sets up the data if they were using the product.

Comment: Also might you not still have the same issue I describe? Let's say your 'Givens' are in a separate class to your 'Whens'. You could use context injection to transfer some state to the when class for a particular step, but what if there is another step in that same class that doesn't require that state? You still need to inject something to prevent a specflow error. You can't for example set up multiple constructors with different state/objects injected to cater for when the state is or isn't required.

Comment: No.  The point of given(s) statement are to set the system into a known given state.  I.e. given i have a user with the following details. Then use a specflow table to parameterize the step   You can chain givens with ands to create a more complex system state.  Having constructors that sometimes use values is a code smell regardless as a general programming practice

Comment: I disagree. Given is used to describe an initial state, not describe how you got to that initial state by way of data setup. In your example what if you need a user, and you need a system setting set, and you need certain records linked to your user etc. Your chained Givens and Ands start to muddy the scenario and is largely irrelevant to what you are actually trying to test. You will also need to duplicate this gherkin everywhere you need a similar data setup.

Comment: You could try to simplify the given statement so that it covers all your data setup, but this will be a challenge grammatically and if it's too broad, will make it less reusable. Regarding the code smell, I agree, hence the question, but how else should you share data between step binding classes where the steps may or may not utilise the injected data? The documentation suggests a wrapper or 'context' to share with 'interested' step bindings classes. This is the approach I'll opt for, still conceding not everything in the context will be relevant to every step binding.

Comment: From the [Gherkin reference](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#steps).  The purpose of Given steps is to put the system in a known state before the user (or external system) starts interacting with the system (in the When steps). Avoid talking about user interaction in Given’s. If you were creating use cases, Given’s would be your preconditions.

Comment: Can you post your scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to share data between steps, not step bindings. The way to do this in SpecFlow is by using the scenario context to set data in one step and retrieve it in another step. For instance, I would have a step called `Given an apprenticeship exists`. The step definition for this would be something like:

```
[Binding]
public class ApprenticeshipSteps
{
    private readonly ScenarioContext scenario;

    public ApprenticeshipSteps(ScenarioContext scenario)
    {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    [Given(@"an apprenticeship exists")]
    public void GivenAnApprenticeshipExists()
    {
        var apprenticeship = new Apprenticeship(...);

        scenario["apprenticeship"] = apprenticeship;

        // save to database if need be
    }
}

[Binding]
public class MoreStepDefinitions
{

    private readonly ScenarioContext scenario;

    public MoreStepDefinitions(ScenarioContext scenario)
    {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    [Then(@"a step that needs the apprenticeship")]
    public void AnotherStep()
    {
        var apprenticeship = (Apprenticeship)scenario["apprenticeship"];
    }
}
```

If need be you can put the apprenticeship Id in the scenario context instead if you need to get it from the database. The scenario context is basically just a bag of data passed around from step definition to step definition. This is the preferred way to share data between steps in SpecFlow.